# Camel Route with every "step" being event driven

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

Here's my camel route.

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:foo"/>
    <to uri="publish event1" />
    <from uri="kafka event1"/>
    <to uri="publish event2" />
    <from uri="kafka event2)"/>
    <to uri="publish event3" />
    <from uri="kafka event3)"/>
    <to uri="publish event4" />
    <from uri="kafka event4)"/>
</route>
```

I want to be able to:

- Make Every method react to an event from Kafka (Except the first one).

**The above way is just a conceptual representation as one route with multiple from is not allowed.**

I'm not even sure if Camel is the right choice for this orchestration in a "suspended" mode.

Any suggestions? Basically, I want every step to react to events and publish more events for the next steps.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understood too clear . maybe you can add more detail as I understand you need use intercept log incoming roots work for for every jms message

```
interceptFrom("jms*")
  .to("log:incoming");

from("jms:queue:order")
  .to("bean:validateOrder")
  .to("bean:processOrder");
```

for mode detail: https://camel.apache.org/components/next/eips/intercept.html

Comment: Ok, what I actually meant was every endpoint is a kafka listener that gets triggered when an event is raised.